# Block internet access in openVPN when connect to vpn

Tags: openvpn

I install and config openVPN in my Ubuntu server using this tutorial and everything is work, but i want to block internet access when user active vpn

i use this configuration base on some search in internet but it not work and user still access to internet

in server.conf or base.conf add this lines

```
script-security 2
up /etc/openvpn/block_internet.sh
down /etc/openvpn/unblock_internet.sh
```

also create block_internet.sh and make it excutable:

```
#!/bin/bash
iptables -A FORWARD -s $ifconfig_pool_remote_ip -j DROP
```

and for unblock_internet.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
iptables -D FORWARD -s $ifconfig_pool_remote_ip -j DROP
```

I run VPN server(vmware) and client in a local network may be this is the problem?

Comment: What is the value of `$ifconfig_pool_remote_ip`?

Comment: It's a placeholder that is automatically replaced with the actual IP address of the connecting client